# Entire Excel Comma Separated Data in a Single Column

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, excel

I've Implemented the Functionality for Downloading the Excel of the records. I have two columns in Data that need to be displayed in a separate cell in Excel but in the downloaded excel, the data is coming in a single cell with a comma in between them.

```
else if(component.get("v.picklistSelected") == 'Excel' && !$A.util.isUndefined(component.get("v.picklistSelected"))){
        if($A.util.isUndefined(component.get("v.listofID")[0])){
        helper.showToastMessage(component,event,'Error','No records to download');
        return;
    }else{
        var action = component.get('c.downloadlist');
        action.setParams({                
            'listofID' : component.get("v.listofID"),
            'listName' : component.get("v.listName"),
        });           
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){  
            var state = response.getState(); 
            if (state === "SUCCESS"){
                var resp = response.getReturnValue();
                var records = resp.records;
                var fieldAPI = resp.fieldAPI;
                var columnsName= resp.fieldLabels;
                var data = [];
                var csv = columnsName + '\n';
                for(var t in records){
                    var ladd = [];
                    for(var s in fieldAPI){
                        try{
                            var returnText = helper.returnData(fieldAPI[s],records[t],component);
                            if(returnText != null){
                                returnText = returnText.toString();
                                if(returnText.includes('"')){
                                    returnText = returnText.toString();
                                    var returnTextArray = returnText.split('"');
                                    var returnTextTemp = '';
                                    if(returnText.startsWith('"')){
                                        returnTextTemp += '""';
                                    }
                                    if(returnTextArray.length > 0){
                                        returnTextTemp += returnTextArray[0];
                                    }
                                    for(var i = 1; i < returnTextArray.length ; i++){
                                        returnTextTemp += '""' + returnTextArray[i];
                                    }
                                    if(returnText != '"' && returnText.endsWith('"')){
                                        returnTextTemp += '""';
                                    }
                                    returnText = returnTextTemp;
                                }
                                returnText = '"'+ returnText +'"';
                                if(returnText.includes('=')){
                                    var n = returnText.indexOf('=');
                                    returnText= returnText.slice(0, n) + " " + returnText.slice(n);
                                }
                            }                           
                            ladd.push(returnText);
                        }catch(err){
                            ladd.push(' ');   
                        } 
                    }
                    data.push(ladd);               
                }
                for(var i in data){
                    if(data[i] === 'null'){
                        var row = '';
                    }else{
                        var row = Object.values(data[i]);
                    }
                    csv += row.join(',');
                    csv += "\n";
                }

                var blob = new Blob([csv],{type: 'text/plain'});    
                var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
                var csvUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                hiddenElement.href = csvUrl;
                hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
                hiddenElement.download = 'Segment.xls';
                document.body.appendChild(hiddenElement);
                hiddenElement.click();
                document.body.removeChild(hiddenElement);
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }

returnData : function(fieldAPI,record,component){ 
        var isParentField = fieldAPI.indexOf('.') != -1 ? true : false;
        if(!isParentField){ 
            var nameSpace = component.get("v.orgNameSpace");
            var value;
            if(!$A.util.isEmpty(nameSpace) && component.get("v.listofID")[0] != undefined){
                value = !fieldAPI.includes('TestNamespace__') && fieldAPI.includes('__c') ? record[nameSpace+fieldAPI] : record[fieldAPI];
            }else if((!$A.util.isEmpty(nameSpace) && component.get("v.listofID")[0] == undefined) || $A.util.isEmpty(nameSpace)){
                value = record[fieldAPI];
            }
            return value;
        }else{
            var parentFieldAPI = fieldAPI.split(/\.(.+)/)[0];
            var parentRecord = record[parentFieldAPI];
            fieldAPI = fieldAPI.split(/\.(.+)/)[1];
           return this.returnData(fieldAPI,parentRecord, component);     
        }
    }
```

[image: The Screenshot of the Excel which I gets on downloading]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be a parsing error; you told the system that this was a plain text file. Use the correct Mime Type:

```
var blob = new Blob([csv],{type: 'text/csv'});
```

The only other situation may be that you've accidentally escaped the the entire row by including `""` at the beginning and end of each line. Your CSV parsing is a bit weird, so you may want to review what happens with various inputs.

P.S. CSVs are a Solved Problem. I suggest that you simply use a library like [Papa Parse](https://www.papaparse.com/) to ease the translation to/from CSV.

Comment: Additionally, Use \t for moving to next cell in case of .xls and , for .csv and \n is common for both. This will help you in creating excel in the required format that is .xls and .csv respectively.